# Computer Vision Website Image Slideshow help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, tiff, animated-gif

I'm making an online display of the output of a computer vision algorithm.  After running the algorithm I am left with a folder of about 1000 16 bit .tiff files.  I need to put those on the website in a list for so that the researchers can click through and find the list.  Also there needs to be an image frame with an "animated gif" feel that can be started stopped and played in reverse.  Any ideas on the best way to do this? What language to use? I made a simple website in Ruby on Rails but I don't know if it has the capabilities to do what I require.

Comment: The first portion is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885038/converting-a-16-bit-tiff-file-to-something-viewable-online/2885146#2885146

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just wanted to describe what I was doing in case people didn't see that other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is the answer to both parts of your question.  Here's a [tutorial](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html) on how to make an animated gif with it.

Comment: imagemagick helped me with the conversion part but I do not want to make a true animated gif.  It will be gif like in the fact that it can be played but it needs to be stoppable, startable, and able to be reversed. As well as be able to do frame select from a list.

Comment: Then it sounds like something you could do with flash, which I know next to nothing about.